# IOException: Changed index specification

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I am developing a GWT 2.5.1 and GAE/J 1.7.6 web app using Eclipse Juno/Google Plugin for Eclipse, and I am experimenting with the Search API. After an upgrade to the 1.7.6 GAE SDK the following started happening:

1. When the app is running in GAE Dev Mode and my index is populated,
   it's subsequently programmatically accessible.
2. If the Dev Mode is
   terminated and started again, programmatic access attempts fail (no results returned) as
   follows:

   ```
   SEVERE: Failed to access index
   java.io.IOException: Changed index specification for description_index
   at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LuceneDirectoryMap.getDirectory(LuceneDirectoryMap.java:198)
   at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LuceneDirectoryMap$FileBased.getDirectory(LuceneDirectoryMap.java:64)
   at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.search(LocalSearchService.java:438)
   ```

Since the Search API is in development I would much rather use the SDK with the latest bugfixes and improvements. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding the cause of the exception?

### Update

Fixed in App Engine SDK for Java release 1.7.7.1, available from the [App Engine Downloads page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix released in 1.7.7.1 SDK for Java. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9088)

Answer (score 1):

Today, we found the same problem, our only possible fix on this moment was to change the appengine sdk for version 1.7.5 / 1.7.4.

I suppose there are significant changes coming, but until they're stable, we should not use or depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

An issue has been opened for this in Google Code:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9088

If you believe this problem is important for you, and the workaround is not sufficient, then make sure to star the issue so that it gets escalated for repair.